# Changes made in detailed view should reflect in the collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have  implemented a collection view which has number of images and if I select an image it will go to the detail view where I can view the image in full size and also edit the image.
Now I want to save the edited image so that it should get reflected in the collection view cell. 
ie. when I go back to Collection View the edited image should be there instead the original image. 
Can anybody please help me to do this?

I have used prepareForsegue function to go for detailed view from collection view, as shown below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "ImageView") {

        let cell = sender as PhotoCollection
        var destination = segue.destinationViewController as ImageViewController
        destination.newImage = cell.imageView.image!

    }
```

Comment: Either use a delegate to pass the information back, or you can use an unwind segue to go back, and pass the information in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion. i tried but couldn't get. Can you please explain bit more with an example. Thanks in advance!!!